# How to lock parent rows in NSOutlineView populated by NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an `NSOutlineView` that is populated from an array via an `NSTreeController`. I would like to make it so that rows that have children are not editable and popups in those rows are hidden. You can see my outlineview in the attached screenshot – it's essentially a tree of settings.

How can I go about this or do I need to implement the datasource via a delegate instead of using the NSTreeController to do it?

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)?

Specifically interesting are

```
– outlineView:shouldEditTableColumn:item:
```

which allows to determine if an item can be edited. Just check for children, if item is an parent and `return NO;`

Hiding the popup buttons depends on how you have setup your `NSOutlineView`. In a cell-based outline view use for example

```
– outlineView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:item:
```

to hide cell content for parent rows. In a view based outline view another method comes into play to customize certain columns:

```
– outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:
```

This should be easy to use to achieve your results.

Comment: OK cool this helps but I'm not sure about the last step – actually hiding the cell (I'm using cell-based). I tried using `[cell setHidden:YES]` but that throws unrecognized selector

Comment: make sure you hide the popup button... i don't know the cell setup by heart, but the popup button could be an element of the cell

Comment: The cell is actually an NSPopUpButtonCell, so the error is `[NSPopUpButtonCell setHidden:]: unrecognized selector`

Comment: you could try to set the cell transparent and disable it so clicks don't get through.

Comment: As an alternative consider using a view based outline view which allows to use custom views per row and column.

Comment: I tried `setTransparent` but with the same results. `setEnabled:NO` works but nothing relating to the visibility it seems? I'm not sure how the view based solution would work, i tried enabling that mode but it seems like it will need more to get it binding (all the rows were just said 'table view cell') and I'm not sure how it would solve the problem following that?

Comment: View-based outline view needs a single delegate method to return a view for each row/column which can be predefined in Xcode. You than can return different views for parent / child rows thus one with and one without the popup. To get a better understanding reading up on view-based table views will help.